# Problema en php con remitente de formulario

Tags: php

tenemos un formulario en php que funciona correctamente excepto porque el remitente no es el de quien envía la consulta sino la siguiente dirección
`cgi-mailer@kundenserver.de`

¿que podría ser lo que esta mal configurado en el codigo php?

```
// Read the form values
$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['name'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
$phone = isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' 0-9]/", "", $_POST['phone'] ) : "";
$body = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";
$subject = 'Petición enviada a través del formulario de contacto de Pazo Catoira';
// If all values exist, send the email
$headers = "De: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . "> To: " . RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
$message = "Equipo Administrativo: ".RECIPIENT_NAME." ".$body;

if(mail(RECIPIENT_EMAIL, $subject, $message, $headers)){
       echo "<p class='success'>Gracias por contactar con Pazo Catoira. Recibirá su respuesta a la mayor brevedad posible</p>";

} else {
    echo "Su email no fue enviado";
}

?>
```

Comment: Deberías añadir la definición de las variables implicadas, por ejemplo, $headers y RECIPIENT_EMAIL

Comment: Al menos por la convención de nombres, todo parece indicar que `RECIPIENT_EMAIL` es una constante definida en otra parte del código, y es muy probable que esa constante tenga el valor `cgi-mailer@kundenserver.de`. Si tú quieres otra dirección, sólo tienes que cambiarla aquí: `mail($tuOtraVariable, $subject, $message, $headers)`  y cambiarla también en `$headers`, por el dato que quieres que aparezca.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido correctamente vuestro problema, la cuestión es que el correo que reciben tiene como origen el correo "cgi-mailer@kundenserver.de".

Eso es completamente normal, ya que el correo lo envía realmente el gestor que han instalado y configurado en su servidor para realizar esa operación, es decir, que el correo lo envía realmente el servidor donde tienen alojada su WEB y no lo envía el cliente con su gestor propio de correo, y por eso NO les aparece la dirección "real" del "cliente".

Es por eso que deberían poner los datos del cliente que les contacta en otro lugar, por ejemplo en el cuerpo del mensaje o incluso en el campo subject.